# How to solve congruence equation using table of congruence?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

The question first tells us to build the addition table and multiplication table of congruence class modulo 11.

Now we need to solve X:

> $$3x + 5 \equiv 2 \pmod{11}$$

I know how to find $3x \equiv 2 \pmod{11}$ (from the multiplication table) which is $x = 8$ but with $+5$ in the equation I don't know how to do it. Do I just sum it $8 + 5 = 13$?

Comment: $3x+5\equiv 2 \implies 3x\equiv -3\equiv 8 \pmod {11}$ (note:  the solution to $3x \equiv -3$ is obvious).

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't get this, how does 3x ≡ -3 ?

Comment: Arithmetic works $\pmod {11}$.  Just add $-5$ to both sides, to see get $3x+5-5\equiv 2-5 $ which is the same as $3x\equiv -3$.

Comment: You can think about this as solving two equations in a row: first, $y+5\equiv2\pmod{11}$ (which you can do using the addition table), and then $3x\equiv y\pmod{11}$ (which you can do using the multiplication table).

Comment: There are only 11 numbers to check!!

Answer (score 1):

One could also find some integer K and multiply the whole equation by it. The integer in particular is one such that $3k\equiv 1\bmod 11 $. You can find this by using the Euclidean Algorithm or just by eyeballing it.
Let m be the dividend, n be the divisor, and q be the amount of times n goes into m leaving you with a positive remainder r.

$m\;n\;q\;r$ $\quad$This is the equation $m-(n*q)=r$

$11\;3\;3\;2$ $\quad11-(3*3)=2$

$3\;2\;1\;1$  $\quad3-(2*1)=1$

Using the Extended Euclidean Algorithm you can find such a k that works.
Let's start with the second line and work our way up.
$1=3-(2*1)$
Substituting this into the first line yields
$1=3-(1*(11-3*3))=(3*4)-(11*1)$

From here, we have found our k such that $3k\equiv 1 \bmod 11$

If you multiply your original equation by $k=4$, you get
$4(3x+5)\equiv (2*4) \bmod 11$

This simplifies down to $12x+20\equiv 8 \bmod 11$. See that $12\equiv 1\bmod 11$

Thus, $x+20\equiv8\bmod 11$.

Adding $-20$ to both sides yields
$x\equiv -12\bmod 11$

Now add $22$ to both sides. Note that $22\equiv 0 \bmod 11$

$x+22\equiv 10 \bmod 11$ which simplifies to $x\equiv 10\bmod 11$

Feel free to comment if you are confused about anything. Note: this is one of my first answers so I am sorry about the quality.

Answer (score 0):

For

$3x + 5 \equiv 2 \pmod{11}$

we can use the addition table
[image]

and so

$3x  \equiv 8 \pmod{11}$

and we turn to the multiplication table
[image]

Finally,

$x  \equiv 10 \pmod{11}$